# how to check whether payload has correct information in python

Tags: python, rest, flutter, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using aws api gateway with lambda boto3 to do basic rest communication between client and my server.

My client side uses flutter so I used JsonSerializable package to create a class for each request and response. This not only helps me organize my API calls but also throws errors when I'm using it incorrectly, which makes my life easier.

However, on the server side, I'm using python with boto3. For any `POST` requests, I simply do `json.loads(event['body'])` and from there access the payload using keys. This makes it really hard to keep track of things. And because I'm not throwing any errors even if the payload does not contain correct data, I often spend too much time debugging by printing bunch of stuff and going through them line by line. Is there a way I can create some sort of template (or class, struct, etc) that can check if my payload contains correct data?

Comment: You could create Python classes that are initialised from the dictionary and throw an error if data is "wrong". This way, if the class can be instantiated you know it has "valid" data. But you would have to code that yourself. Maybe you could use a factory pattern (not sure if that is a thing in Python). Since Python does not have a proper type system, you might want to switch to a language that does, if you have an issue with this. The great thing about Lambdas is, that you can write them in a lot of languages.

Comment: @moneyball- Instead of tracing such issues within application logic, I would suggest to have a option of using following services from AWS;

1) [AWS X-Ray](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/new-analyze-and-debug-distributed-applications-interactively-using-aws-x-ray-analytics/)
2) [AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/introducing-cloudwatch-lambda-insights/) 3) If you still go for tracing within application, then have a look at [Lambda Powertools](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/simplifying-serverless-best-practices-with-lambda-powertools/)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you want to get an in-depth debugging of your invocations and examine the events.

There are a few options to do it.
First, you can simply print the event. This works for a very small number of invocations.

Another option is X-RAY, which is AWS's solution to distributed tracing. It allows examining a specific lambda invocation with an additional transactional flow (which other resources it called etc.). More details here: https://aws.amazon.com/xray/.

Last, there are other 3rd party solutions, that can give you stronger capabilities. For example, in [Lumigo](http://lumigo.io/) you can perform cross-invocations queries to find the bad invocations, and also understand the consequences of the execution.

Disclaimer: I'm working for Lumigo, and I thought that it provides a perfect solution to your problem.